# How to Use Group By on the Basis of Column Value?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, count, pivot

I am trying to use Group By but unable to achieve the output
I want to Group by with Date, shift and with Mass.

**Data is like :**

```
date     | shift | mass 
---------+-------+------
01-05-20 | A     | 5
01-05-20 | B     | 3
01-05-20 | B     | 3
02-05-20 | A     | 11
02-05-20 | A     | 5
02-05-20 | C     | 12
02-05-20 | C     | 12
02-05-20 | B     | 5
```

**OutPut which i want**

```
date     | shift | mass>3 | mass>10 
---------+-------+--------+--------
01-05-20 | A     | 1      | 0
01-05-20 | B     | 2      | 0
02-05-20 | A     | 1      | 1
02-05-20 | B     | 1      | 0
02-05-20 | C     | 0      | 2
```

Comment: Are you sure about the results, I think you need to count the case where mass strictly greater then 3 and 10 for each date, shift group, don't you ?

Comment: i want result for each shift for a date with count of different mass conditions. Like for Mass>3 count for Shift A, B, C

Comment: So, as an example; we need to get 0 for shift B of May 1 for the column mass>3(`>` is strict not `>=` ), but not 2. Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Conditional Aggregation` through `GROUP`ing `BY mydate,shift` :

```
SELECT mydate,shift,
       SUM(CASE WHEN mass > 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "mass>3",
       SUM(CASE WHEN mass >10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "mass>10"
  FROM t
 GROUP BY mydate,shift
 ORDER BY mydate,shift;
```

By the way( *as you asked for it within a comment* ), you can also use `DECODE()` function :

```
SELECT mydate,shift,
       SUM(DECODE(SIGN(mass-3),1,1,0)) AS "mass>3",
       SUM(DECODE(SIGN(mass-10),1,1,0)) AS "mass>10"
  FROM t
 GROUP BY mydate,shift
 ORDER BY mydate,shift
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fed227e29d12b614a429afea12436e08)</kbd>

Comment: I got my result, but i just need explanation, why we are using Sum, just explain that line so it will be helpful for me to learn the new things.

Comment: Since, count aggregation counts every cases without looking matching with your conditional @ShahnawazAhmad .

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> with t(mydate, shift, mass) as
  2  (
  3   select '01-05-2020', 'A', 5 from dual union all
  4   select '01-05-2020', 'B', 3 from dual union all
  5   select '01-05-2020', 'B', 3 from dual union all
  6   select '02-05-2020', 'A', 11 from dual union all
  7   select '02-05-2020', 'A', 5 from dual union all
  8   select '02-05-2020', 'C', 12 from dual union all
  9   select '02-05-2020', 'C', 12 from dual union all
 10   select '02-05-2020', 'B', 5 from dual
 11  )
 12  SELECT mydate,shift,
 13         SUM(CASE WHEN mass >=3 AND
 14                       mass < 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "mass>=3",
 15         SUM(CASE WHEN mass >10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "mass>10"
 16    FROM t
 17   GROUP BY mydate,shift
 18   ORDER BY mydate,shift;

MYDATE     S    mass>=3    mass>10
---------- - ---------- ----------
01-05-2020 A          1      0
01-05-2020 B          2      0
02-05-2020 A          1      1
02-05-2020 B          1      0
02-05-2020 C          0      2

SQL> 
SQL>
```

Comment: can i use decode instead of case and thanks for the solution.

Comment: Yes see above solution.

Comment: @ShahnawazAhmad . . . `case` is preferable because it is standard SQL.